# How to determine the datatype in Python?

Tags: python

astring
('a','tuple')

How do I determine if "x" is a tuple or string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if isinstance(x, basestring):
   # a string
else:
   try: it = iter(x)
   except TypeError:
       # not an iterable
   else:
       # iterable (tuple, list, etc)
```

[@Alex Martelli's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/differences-between-isinstance-and-type-in-python/1549854#1549854) describes in detail why you should prefer the above style when you're working with types in Python (thanks to @Mike Hordecki for the link).

Comment: +1, `isinstance(x, str)` and `type(x) is str` are both wrong as they don't handle unicode. Also, `isinstance()` is preferred over `type()` since it handles subclasses.

Answer (score 5):

```
isinstance(x, str)
isinstance(x, tuple)
```

In general:

```
isinstance(variable, type)
```

Checks whether `variable` is an instance of `type` (or its subtype) ([docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#isinstance)).

PS. Don't forget that strings can also be in [unicode](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#index-809) (`isinstance(x, unicode)` in this case) (or `isinstance(x, basestring)` (thanks, J.F. Sebastian!) which checks for both `str` and `unicode`).

Comment: The str vs. unicode distinction disappears in Python 3 - unicode and str are now just str.

Answer (score 0):

use `isinstance()`, general syntax is:

```
if isinstance(var, type):
    # do something
```